# IDE/debugger's stop exec button

Tags: c++, c, debugging

Suppose I have dynamically allocated variables in the program run by the debugger, is it safe to press the stop button of the IDE or stop the debugger? I mean safe...will the variables get deleted/deallocated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is safe.

When a program exits, all the allocated resources returned to the operating system.